# How can i convert string value to rial money unit?

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in c# and have this value of string:

```
123456
```

but want convert that string to my country money, want convert that string value to this:

```
123,456
```

always split three numbers with comma for example, if string number is this:

```
1234567890
```

Show to user this:

```
1,234,567,890
```

How can i write code that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest convert it to `int` (or `long`)  first and then use `ToString()` and supply required format.

```
int number = int.Parse(numberString);  //ex..
number.ToString("N0");  // 1,000,000
```

If you're asking about culture-specific formatting, then you could do this.

```
number.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-US"));
```

You can explore more on [`standard numeric formats`](http://Standard%20Numeric%20Format)

Example [`code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6wS9K)

Comment: Be aware. Predifined string format of "N" only shows 2 decimal point values.

Comment: this just puts commas in the number it doesn't add the currency symbol

Comment: To future readers, you can use `C0` instead of `N0` to get the currency symbol added.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [standard formatters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx) for the desired country.

e.g

```
int i = int.Parse("123456");
string money = i.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-Ir"));
```

Or if the system culture is fr-Ir

```
string money = i.ToString("C");
```

Which is the same as

```
string money = i.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Or if you want to use the UI culture (the culture of the requesting browser)

```
string money = i.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to convert your value to currency, I would suggest using "C" of `string formats` provided by .NET.

```
123456.125M.ToString("C"); // $123,456.13
```

Sign infront of the `string` will be defined by the culture of your machine. More information [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

On the other hand, there is another solution to add your own custom format:

```
123456.125M.ToString("#,0.################"); // 123,456.125
```

It is not the clean way, but I have not since found a correct way of actually formating this in generic way.

Side note: for currency handling it is generally considered a good practise to use `decimal`. Since it does not have a floating point issue.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this one hope will help

Just whats inside the void method

```
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public  void ABC()
    {


        var data = "123456789";
        const int separateOnLength = N;

        var separated = new string(
         data.Select((x,i) => i > 0 && i % separateOnLength == 0 ? new [] { ',', x } : new [] { x })
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToArray()
    );

    }
}
```